# Exception occurs when try to parse xml containing special characters

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, ascii

Everyone
I am developing an app that uses xml as communication protocol between client and server. When server sends the response, the response contains user names. Now user names are expected to contain special characters. When following line executes, i see that CXMLDocument fails to parse such xml document.

```
CXMLDocument *theXMLDocument = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:response options:0 error:&theError] autorelease];
```

Where response is string containing xml document. 
By special characters, i mean extended ASCII characters which have ASCII value greater then 128. Does anyone has any solution of this problem? 
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you read in response, you need to make sure you use the correct character encoding to turn the raw data into a string.

The XML document usually specifies the encoding at the beginning of the file in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                              ^^^^^ the encoding that was used in the file.
```

Of course, it could be lying.  At any rate, to create your string you need to specify the encoding that was used by the server that generated the data.

So I'm guessing here, but somewhere you probably have something like

```
response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseData encoding: someEncoding];
```

You need to make sure the encoding is the encoding that was used to create the XML message you are decoding.